# Data from database wont show up in DataGridView [VB.NET]

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

we are tasked to make a record keeping system for our programming subject so we are making a system for a small Truck company and my user (coordinator) should be able to view info he/she has inputted in the database. In my View Reports form, there is a DataGridView in which the data inputted should appear, however whenever I run it the DataGridView shows nothing, not even the column names from the database it is just as if I added a new DataGridView from the Toolbox.

Here is my code inside the DataGridView:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        Dim conn As New 
        MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=4444;database=database")
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from truck_info", conn)

        adapter.Fill(table)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any rows in your table after executing the query? Any errors? Do you need to open the connection? Should you possibly move this code to a generic method otherwise it'll fire for each CellContentClick?

Comment: As @AndrewMortimer suggests, you have the code in the wrong place.  If there are no columns in the grid then there are no cells, so how can the user click the content of a cell?  That code should be in the the `Load` event handler of the form or the `Click` of a `Button` or somewhere else sensible like that.

Comment: The datagridview doesn't automatically repaint when data is changed.  In c# we normall set the  DataGridView1.DataSource = null and then back to   DataGridView1.DataSource = table

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank youuu! This gave me an idea where to place the code. I placed it in the Load event handler! :)

Comment: My code now works, man should have posted earlier! Thank you so much for the comments, it gave me an idea to place codes correctly and to analyze them thoroughly :D

Answer (score 0):

I would just add one thing to the excellent comments. Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using blocks take care of this even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=4444;database=database")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from truck_info", conn)
            conn.Open()
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
```